# how to parse a DataTable from webservice using wdsl2objc class

Tags: iphone, web-services, datatable, wsdl2objc

i have a  problem when i get a DataTable from WebService using wsdl2objc.the webservice was written using .net and the GetUserInfo method returns a DataTable.

```
for (id mine in response.bodyParts){
    if([mine isKindOfClass:[Mobile_GetUserInfoResponse class]]){
        Mobile_GetUserInfoResponse *res = (Mobile_GetUserInfoResponse *)mine;
        Mobile_GetUserInfoResult *getUserInfoResult  = res.GetUserInfoResult;
        //what to do next?
    }
}
```

i got the getUserInfoResult,but how can i get the data from it

thx.

Comment: Since you are using wsdl, the `Mobile_GetUserInfoResult` will have an implementation in the wsdl2objc generated class. Simply you'll need to get its values through `getUserInfoResult.yourValue`

Comment: getUserInfoResult has no value can be readed.

    @interface Mobile_GetUserInfoResult : NSObject {

}

- (NSString *)nsPrefix;
- (xmlNodePtr)xmlNodeForDoc:(xmlDocPtr)doc elementName:(NSString *)elName elementNSPrefix:(NSString *)elNSPrefix;
- (void)addAttributesToNode:(xmlNodePtr)node;
- (void)addElementsToNode:(xmlNodePtr)node;
+ (Mobile_GetUserInfoResult *)deserializeNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur;
- (void)deserializeAttributesFromNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur;
- (void)deserializeElementsFromNode:(xmlNodePtr)cur;
- (NSDictionary *)attributes;

Comment: do you have a `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` in your implementation of `Mobile_GetUserInfoResult` ?